# IF statement + send-mailmessage confused

Tags: powershell, if-statement, powershell-4.0

Quick question;
I want to make a log of bad stuff happening to the servers, but that's not the question.

The log should be deleted upon send, and if there is no log at the time the script is being run it should send a different message, without an attachment.

Here's the script so far:

```
        <#
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Force
iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
cinst BetterCredentials
#>

Import-Module BetterCredentials
$Mailcred = Get-Credential -user user@gmail.com -pass 12345password
Try{
$File = C:/path/errorfile.log
}
Catch [System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException]
 {
  "invalid object"
 }
 Catch [system.exception]
 {
  "caught a system exception"
 }
Finally
 {
If ($File -eq ){
    then (send-mailmessage -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -from "Server         <Server@company.com>" -to "IT Dept. <Itdept@company.com>" -subject "Log of the day." -body             "Good Morning,

    Fortuneatly, nothing bad to report today!" -priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure      -smtpServer smtp.company.com -credential ($Mailcred) -usessl)

        else (send-mailmessage -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -from "Servers     <Server@company.com>" -to "IT Dept. <ITDept@company.com>" -subject "Log of the day." -body     "Good Morning,

        Here is your daily report." -Attachments $File -priority High -dno onSuccess,     onFailure  -smtpServer smtp.company.com -credential ($Mailcred) -usessl)
        }
}
```

What AM I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parts of your code do not make any sense. Let's review those.

```
$File = C:/path/errorfile.log
...
If ($File -eq ){
```

The first part is about assignment. In order to find out wether `errorfile.log` exists, use the `Test-Path` cmdlet like so,

```
$File = test-path 'C:/path/errorfile.log'
```

Always use quotes around file name. If you got spaces within path, unquoted path doesn't work.

The second part is the actual test.

```
If ($File){
... # file was on disk, send alert and delete it
} else {
... # no file found, send ok 
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thanks a million.
Did need a few minutes to figure out to assign a new arg to the file path for sending the actual attachment. :-0

However, you're a life saver! Thank you.

Deleted the Try,Catch,Final lines as well